# Spring boot doesn't package files into jar

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am writing a springboot application which uses mybatis for persistence. I am trying to build using gradlew.sh (a gradle builder shell). The directory structure is like the following

MyApp

└── src

```
    └── main

         └── java
```

└── resources-dev

```
    └── org
        └── myapp
            └── mappers
```

The mappers  directory contains xml mappers for mybatis. 
When I run ./gradlew.sh , neither the xml files nor any other non-java file is packaged into my jar. what am  I missing?

Comment: As far as I know there is no "gradlew.sh" packaged with Spring Boot anywhere (it's a Gradle feature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional location for classpath resources is "src/main/resources". If you stick to the convention (from Gradle not from Spring) you will have an easier time, although I'm sure there is a way to customize the build config if you read the Gradle docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to customize your resources location :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by resorting to maven packaging and specifying my resources in the pom.xml.